# Почему папки Яндекс почта на английском вместо русского в Outlook 2016(IMAP)?

Tags: email, imap, outlook, яндекс-почта

Проблема заключается в неправильном отображении папок (Отправленные, Удаленные и т.д.). Они отображаться английскими названиями Sent, Trash etc. Самое главное, что у меня есть два почтового ящика на Яндекс Почта, которые настраиваю одним и тем же мастером в Outlook 2016 и для одного папки именуются правильно русскими названиями, а для другого английскими. Излазил все настройки в Яндекс Почта но никаких различий не нашел. В чем может быть дело?
Спасибо.

Comment: Есть софт, есть сайт, есть протокол imap4 эти вещи между собой напрямую никак не связаны. Т.е. если софт поддерживает русский - интерфейс русский вне зависимости что там с imap и с сайтом в.т.ч настройками на сайте. Если проблема с софтом - настраивайте софт, ищите патчи на этот софт или ищите другой софт.

Comment: Лучше так (первоисточник на microsoft.com)
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/incorrect-folder-names

Answer (score 1):

В Яндекс.Почте вы таких настроек и не найдёте. Яндекс.Почта тут вообще не при чём. Не зависимо от того, как вы видите имена этих ящиков - на самом почтовом сервере они всё равно будут именоваться на английском. То, что в Outlook у вас отображаются русские названия - так это он сам просто "преобразует" их с учётом языка системы или выбранных настроек. Проверяйте настройки Outlook'а - его общие параметры или настройки учётных записей.

Comment: По-моему ответ "ищите где-то там в настройках или других настройках" лучше писать в комментарии.

Comment: Мне казалось я правильно выразил мысль, что есть **2** почтовый ящика на Яндекс Почта. Один отображается **правильно** с русскими именами папок, а другой **неправильно**. Настройка происходила одним и тем же методом, что говорит о том, что **не настройки программы** влияют на не правильно отображение папок.

Comment: В общем случае IMAP клиент не отображает по-русски. Он отображает имена папок, как они созданы на сервере. В одном случае папки уже были созданы на сервере с русскими именами (клиентом, который по умолчанию называет папки по-русски). Во втором случае вы использовали клиентское ПО, которое назыввает папки по-английски. Зайдите в аккаунты через Web и убедитесь. И заодно переименуйте папки так, как вам удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут виноват не аутлук, а яндекс почта. Разработчики сами говорят, что подпапок у них нет, но некоторые клиенты их отображают http://it-time.site/42-kak-v-jandekspochte-sozdat-papku-vnutri-vhodjaschih.html

Answer (score 0):

Собственно о проблеме. Созданные почтовые ящики на яндексе, необходимо было подключить к Outlook по протоколу imap (на pop3 название папок было на русском). При подключении по "imap" в outlook отображалась на русском языке только папка "Входящие" все остальные были на английском. Пользователи очень плохо дружат с ПК в принципе, а тут еще и папки на английском.

Перерыл весь интернет, много кто писал про "запуск outlook с ключом /resetfoldernames. Но лично у меня не срабатывало т.к. в Outlooke был еще один аккаунт от google на pop3 протоколе. И файл базы данных "по умолчанию" использовался именно тот от pop3 аккаунта.

Решение:

1. Настраиваете нужные аккаунта в Outlook.
2. В Outlook (пример 2013) заходите в "файл-> параметры-> язык- в окошках где будет выбор языков, во всех трех включаете по умолчанию русский язык.
3. В Outlook файл-> настройка учетных записей - включаете по умолчанию "электронную почту" и "файлы данных" именно тот аккаунт на котором нужно перевести папки на русский язык.
4. Закрываете Outlook (закрыть нужно полностью, что бы не остались вкладки с "создать новое сообщение" или еще какие то вкладки.
5. Создаете ярлык с ключом. В моем случае путь ярлыка: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /resetfoldername
6. Откроется Outlook с папками на русском языке того аккаунта, который был включен по умолчанию.

Если в вашем Outlook есть еще аккаунты, в котором так-же нужно перевести папки на русский язык, просто повторяйте пункт №3 с каждым следующим аккаунтом.

Answer (score 0):

В яндекс почте входим в настройки (шестеренка сверху справа), в выпавшей таблице нажимаем на любой раздел, слева видим слово language - english? меняем на русский